# How to gracefully pre-process code in IPython?

Tags: python, ipython

The main question is - how in the perfect way make custom processing for the line input in IPython console?

The IPython console is embedded in my Python application. 
In my application I have the old version of the console, based on `code.InteractiveConsole`. There is a processing in `InteractiveConsole.raw_input` method, and it works. Where is an analog in IPython?

Digging the documentation, I've found `input_transformers_cleanup` looks good for my aim. But how to use it? My invocation `get_ipython()` returns None and I'm not sure that is the right way.

Thanks.

Comment: Digging through [the sources](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/blob/master/IPython/core/inputtransformer2.py) often helps a lot.

Comment: Sorry, the answer is not informative. This module is for form basic input. But, maybe, I have to override 'run_cell' method? And which way shall I do that?

Comment: This is not a proper answer, just I link that could have been useful.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, here is my pattern:

```
import IPython
# IPython.start_ipython(config=c)

from traitlets import Type
from IPython.terminal.interactiveshell import TerminalInteractiveShell

class MyTerminalInteractiveShell(TerminalInteractiveShell):
    def run_cell(self, raw_cell, store_history=False, silent=False, shell_futures=True):
        print("Override successful!!!", raw_cell)
        super(MyTerminalInteractiveShell, self).run_cell(raw_cell, store_history, silent, shell_futures)

class MyTerminalIPythonApp(IPython.terminal.ipapp.TerminalIPythonApp):
    interactive_shell_class = Type(
        klass=object,   # use default_value otherwise which only allow subclasses.
        default_value=MyTerminalInteractiveShell,
        help="Class to use to instantiate the TerminalInteractiveShell object. Useful for custom Frontends"
    ).tag(config=True)

app_class = MyTerminalIPythonApp
app = app_class.instance(config=c)
app.initialize()
app.start()
```